# Active character count of wtforms TextAreaField

Tags: flask, flask-wtforms

### What I'm trying to do

I'm trying to set up a form that includes a TextFieldArea.
So far, I have several validators in place, including a character limit.
Now I'd like to display the current character count below the TextFieldArea, for usability.

Like this:

[image: word count]

### The Problem

I have found a lot of really good documentation of [how to do this in JavaScript](http://www.mattmorgante.com/technology/textarea-remaining-characters-javascript), but virtually zero for Python / Flask.

I have the hope that this is can be done with [pre-validators](https://wtforms.readthedocs.io/en/stable/fields.html), or [widgets](https://wtforms.readthedocs.io/en/stable/widgets.html) or template scripts.

### What I tried

```
{{ render_field(form.abstract) }}
          <p>{{form.abstract.gettext}}</p>
```

This is at least returning some kind of object identity. But past that, I'm at a loss.

Comment: It sounds like a pure javascript task where the server side is not involved. Something like: http://www.mattmorgante.com/technology/textarea-remaining-characters-javascript

Comment: I even linked that source.

Comment: :-). OK - so go with a js solution.

Comment: Can you point me in the right direction as to that the go-to way for Flask / Js interaction is supposed to be? Feel free to write an answer with this.

Comment: As far as I understand Flask is not aware to this activity. All you need to have is a 'key' listener that will be attached to the text area. See the link we talked before. So you are going to implement this code inside the HTML page / Jinja template

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used this in the past, found it via google once.

```
function TextCounter(field, limit) {
    var typedChars = $(field).val().length;
    $(field).next('span').text(typedChars=0?'0 / '+limit:typedChars+' / '+limit);
    };
```

and add this to your TextArea field

```
onInput="TextCounter(this, 32)"
```